# Auto-Renewable Subscriptions for Non- Newsstands App

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

1. I am developing one commercial app where i implemented
   Auto-Renewable Subscriptions.
2. I am able to test it properly.

---

- so my Queries are:
- A. Does apple have any restriction for implementing Auto-Renewable
  Subscription for non-newsstands app i.e normal apps ?
- B. I also wanted to implement Free Subscription but it is clearly
  mention by Apple that it is only available for newsstands app. am i
  right? Currently i am handling this using my web services.
  [image]
- C. If apple allows Auto-Renewable Subscription implementation for
  normal app (Non NewSStand Apps) any special care needs to be taken as
  a developer?

---

Thank You

Answer (score 3):

Here are the answers :-

A. Apple doesn't have any restriction for implementing Auto-Renewable Subscription for non-newsstands apps.

B. Free Subscription can't be offered through in-app purchases in non newsstand apps. But if you are doing it using web-services then apple must not have any problem with that. It's just you may need to explain the functionality to them during app review and it will be accepted on app store.

C.Just follow the guidelines regarding implementing Auto-Renewable Subscription. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

May be helpful http://www.marco.org/2012/01/06/autorenewable-subscription-restrictions reference from http://www.raywenderlich.com/36270/in-app-purchases-non-renewing-subscription-tutorial.